# why is this code not working?

Tags: vb6, ado

I wonder why this code is not working?

```
ListView1.ListItems.Clear
' Set RS = New ADODB.Recordset

RS.Open "select nom, note, remarque from table1 WHERE remark=''", DB,    
        adOpenDynamic, adLockOptimistic

ListView1.View = lvwReport

Dim Lst As ListItem

Do While Not RS.EOF
Set Lst = ListView1.ListItems.Add(, , RS!nom)
Lst.SubItems(1) = RS!note
Lst.SubItems(2) = RS!remark
RS.MoveNext

Loop
 End If
```

would anyone help, and correct me the code
I want to retrieve from the dtabase access the records that do not have  remark

Comment: You haven't said what IS happening - are there any errors or does it not behave as it should?  You have clipped your code too much, we can't see what is happening above to set values of `RS` etc and you have an `End If` in the picture but not the opening `If/Then`.  Please expand on the information in your post so we can help you.

Answer (score 0):

While, as joehanna has remarked, you haven't explained what your problem is, I'll put on my tinfoil hat, cross my legs, and chant for a few minutes and see if I can get any psychic impressions of what it is that you need...

Ah.  It looks like you are trying to get all records which have no remark in them, and you aren't getting any of them. (Of course, you haven't mentioned whether you're getting any of them or not, which is why I have to resort to my tinfoil hat. It would be much better if you would simply tell us, instead of just saying that the code isn't working.) This is probably because you are asking for all records where remark has an empty string, and there aren't any.

Typically, if there is no value in a field in a database, the field has the value of NULL.  (Sometimes imported data puts empty strings in fields instead of null values, but usually not.)  I'm going to guess that your problem is that you are looking for an empty string, and the actual value that you need to be looking for is NULL.  If so, I'll let you work out the actual WHERE clause.

Comment: Thank you everyone .My problem is solved.
I'm sorry because it was a stupidity my part.
I used to fill the fields manually on my table which does not give the ppropriate results for my querry.
When I deleted all the fields and I filled the texts via the form all became great
thank you again and I apologize

Answer (score 0):

Thank you everyone. My problem is solved.

I'm sorry because it was a stupidity my part.

I used to fill the fields manually on my table which does not give the ppropriate results for my query.

When I deleted all the fields and I filled the texts via the form all became great
thank you again and I apologize